# Transform Fermionic operators to quantum circuit in qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am trying to realize a modified version of the UCCSD algorithm, which consists of combining multiple fermionic opeators to form a unitary tranformation `U` to act on a reference state that in most case is the Hartree-Fock state. I already got the `U` defined by the ['FermionicOperator'](https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.operators.second_quantization.FermionicOp.html#qiskit_nature.operators.second_quantization.FermionicOp) object. However, it seems that there is no straight way to complie the unitary 'U' to a quantum circuit. Can anybody help me to realize the corresponding circuit?

Comment: Hello, did you try to directly add it to your circuit this way : `qc.append(my_operator, qubit_list)`? (I don't know if this will work, just a hunch since operators from `qiskit.quantum_info` are used this way on circuits)